# How to enable Bluetooth in Mac with shortcut or command line?

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth

I accidentally disabled the Bluetooth on Mac OS. I can't enable it because my Bluetooth based keyboard and mouse are now disabled.

I found a USB based keyboard I can use, so how can I enable Bluetooth just using my keyboard?

Is there a command line way or shortcut I can use?

Comment: I can just imagine the :facepalm: when you realized what happened.  Hope someone has the right answer for you.  :)

Comment: what if my keyboard is also bluetooth ?

Comment: @johnSmith in this case I used my other mac to remote desktop / screen share :) and enabled it remotely.

Answer (score 120):

Here's a sequence that worked for me (OS X 10.6.7) when I had the same issue.

1. Press <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd> to activate Spotlight.
2. Type "bluetooth", choose the 'Bluetooth File Exchange' application, and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.
3. Bluetooth File Exchange will prompt to enable the bluetooth hardware, press <kbd>Return</kbd>.
4. Bluetooth is now enabled and you can quit Bluetooth File Exchange.

Comment: This worked better for me, as I have the function keys set to control playback, and Control+F7 wasn't enabling full keyboard access... Thanks!

Comment: This worked well for me because the On checkbox in the Bluetooth preferences pane was not selectable :-(  OS X Lion

Comment: This worked way better for me than fideli's answer which got me all the way to bluetooth settings but I could not tab to the **on** check box. This was also lot faster and easier.

Comment: Elegant and functional — this was an awesome answer.

Comment: This really is the best solution that I've found to this problem. Very quick to execute, and easy to remember.

Comment: Point 4 seems obsolete in that it quits automatic, no manual need to quit.

Answer (score 37):

I've been using [blueutil](http://www.frederikseiffert.de/blueutil/) occasionally - seems to work. It's free and comes with the source code.

```
blueutil --power 1
blueutil --power 0
```

Older versions:

> **Usage:**
>
> **Print bluetooth status**
>   `blueutil status`
>
> **Switch bluetooth on**
>   `blueutil on`
>
> **Switch bluetooth off**
>   `blueutil off`

Comment: I installed this via brew and the on command was blueutil power 1

Comment: Best answer to this question!

Comment: Sorry if this comment runs counter to (necro) etiquette on this Stack, but I thought it might add something useful... Here's the blueutil-based Bash script I use to toggle Bluetooth on/off: `if [[ $(blueutil status) == 'Status: off' ]] ; then blueutil on ; else blueutil off ; fi`. If you bind this script to a keyboard shortcut e.g. via Karabiner  you get a Bluetooth toggle without resorting to some hacky key event solution.

Comment: Thanks! The best and efficient answer. I have installed with "brew install blueutil" command. "blueutil -p toggle" works without any problem on Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6. If bluetooth power is on, it makes it off. If bluetooth power is off, it makes it on.

Comment: `blueutil` without args shows the `status`, e.g. `on/off`

Answer (score 24):

1. <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> until you get to the Finder.
2. <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to bring up the Go To dialog: type in `/Applications`.
3. Just type the letters "sys" and your highlight should be over "System Preferences". Press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to open it.
4. In System Preferences, the cursor should be in the search field. Just type in "bluetooth" and press Return. Now you're in the Bluetooth preferences.
5. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and there should be a faint highlight on the "On" checkbox.
6. Press <kbd>Space</kbd>, and that should turn it on.

If you happen to have [Quicksilver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksilver_(software)) installed, invoke System Preferences from there and go directly to step 4 above. Or without Quicksilver press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to activate Spotlight, type "bluetooth" and go directly to the Bluetooth preference pane, and step 5 above.

If you don't have a Command key on the keyboard, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to activate the Apple menu, press <kbd>↓</kbd> and go to System Preferences and continue at step 4 above.

If in Step 5 pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not navigate through all inputs, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to activate Full Keyboard Access. When done, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> again to disable it.

Comment: 1-3 can be replaced with: ⌘-space; type "sys"; hit enter. (⌘-space launches Spotlight.)

Comment: This is a great answer!

Comment: Can't highlight the On checkbox with tabbing... change in snow leopard?

Comment: 1-4 can be replaced with: ⌘-space; type "blue"; select Bluetooth, hit enter. (⌘-space launches Spotlight.) :-)

Comment: Ctrl+F7 didn't work for me on Mavericks 10.9.3, but the BlueTooth File Exchange approach worked nicely.

Comment: In 10.10.5: Ctrl F7 didn't work for me either; I did manage to get the "Turn Bluetooth On" highlighted but pressing enter didn't do anything.

Comment: Damn, nice spacebar trick! I tried pressing enter so many times with no luck.

Comment: 1- 3 can be replaced with Option-"brilliance" (on F2 key in my keyboard). That will bring up the system preferences panel.

Answer (score 10):

I wanted to mention a little known feature of the OS:

If you reboot and unplug the keyboard, the OS will automatically enable Bluetooth and start looking for BT keyboards and mice. From [Apple's official documentation](https://support.apple.com/en-vn/HT202300):

> 1. Turn on your Mac.
> 2. If no USB mouse is detected, the Mac will power up to the Bluetooth trackpad or mouse setup assistant. The screen should alternate between an image of the trackpad and one of the mouse, as below.

However, this is apparently controlled by a Bluetooth setting which might be disabled:

[image: Bluetooth Setup Assistant Settings]

If this setting has been disabled by the user (it is enabled by default) then this method will not work.If these options have been disabled, you can re-enable them using the terminal commands:

```
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth BluetoothAutoSeekKeyboard '1'
sudo defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth BluetoothAutoSeekPointingDevice '1'
```

(However you might need to SSH in to do that, a which point one of the other answers might be better)

Comment: This is arguably better than any of the other answers :).  Very little technical knowledge required.

Comment: But what if you don't have a wired keyboard or mouse - only Bluetooth ones?  As far as I can tell the computer won't enable Bluetooth even with a reboot.

Comment: I believe that the login screen will automatically enable Bluetooth if there's no HID devices connected. I'll look for a reference tonight

Comment: @EdAvis: Apple Support Docs say: [1. Turn on your Mac.
2. If no USB mouse is detected, the Mac will power up to the Bluetooth trackpad or mouse setup assistant.](https://support.apple.com/en-vn/HT202300)

Comment: Following some instructions elsewhere, I unplugged *everything* from the iMac, plugged back just the power cord, and then switched it on.  That worked (after a short delay at the login screen when it appeared not to).

Answer (score 5):

Here is a faster way which I just did on Lion:

1. Command + Spacebar to start spotlight
2. type "bluetooth"
3. Select "Bluetooth File Exchange"
4. This will trigger a warning that bluetooth is disabled, the enable button should be highlighted so all you need to do now is press return

Comment: Worked on Mavericks, too!

Comment: works on Catalina.  The only useful answer here.

Comment: Works on Ventura!

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> activates the status menu.(upper right corner)
If bluetooth button is enabled in the status menu, you can select the bluetooth-menu-option using the   <kbd>↑</kbd>    <kbd>←</kbd>  <kbd>↓</kbd>   <kbd>→</kbd>   and  <kbd>return</kbd>   to activate bluetooth

Depending on your keyboard preference settings, you may need to press 
<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

Comment: This sounds like a Windows keyboard shortcut instead of a OS X shortcut.

Comment: I don't really know why anyone down-voted this response. Maybe they didn't actually put in the effort to try it and see it does give a bit of help ? @Ramhound it actually works. I just tested it on my MacBook. I hold down the Fn + CTRL then strike the F8 key and voila ! It selects the Bluetooth in the menubar. With the wired keyboard, the user would then be able to navigate the Bluetooth menu to select his bluetooth settings and reactive his mouse/keyboard. So, yes, it's actually a OS X shortcut, not a Windows shortcut.

Comment: And just to add to this, I think it's ridiculous we all go and down-vote a new user for what reason without at least adding some comments to their answer to be more productive so we know and they know where in future it might be more clear or helpful. I don't know when the votes came in, before or after the comment about this sounding like it's a Windows keyboard shortcut. Did anyone actually bother to try this and compare it against the results of other users ? I don't think so.

Comment: The comment was CTRL+F8 not FN+CTRL+F8.  I made the comment nearly 2 years, the answer honestly, seems incomplete.  I don't find short answers like this very helpful, compared to the other answers, this was a late answers to an old question after 4 years.

Comment: I like the answer and I do not think it deserves down vote - in my mac is configured to use F8 (and all F keys) directly without the need to press fn first. So this answer worked perfectly for me, but the answers above the mentioned fn + Ctrl + F7, for example, did not. Do I need to downvote them - No afcource! Read and try and do not downvote unless it is really off topic.

Comment: I upvoted you. You can change the default behaviour of the F keys, they can act as an F key or as the symbol on them suggests, like volume and stuff. That's why sometimes it works with fn+ctrl and sometimes just with ctrl.

Comment: Or, you know, we could edit the answer to clarify the keyboard setting.

Comment: Doesn't work on Catalina

Answer (score 4):

This method required the bluetooth menu bar status icon to show and used AppleScript GUI scripting (requires *System Preferences » Universal Access » Support for assistive devices* IIRC):

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "SystemUIServer"
        tell (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description is "bluetooth")
            click
            click menu 1's second menu item
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Call from command line using `osascript`:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer" to tell (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1 whose description is "bluetooth") to {click, click (menu item 2 of menu 1)}'
```

<sup>Do not edit this post. I don't care if you don't like the scroll bar. It's easier to select by triple-clicking this way.</sup>

---

Alternatively, you can launch System Preferences and click the checkbox:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane id "com.apple.preferences.bluetooth"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
            click checkbox "On" of window "Bluetooth"
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

While a GUI process launches, it isn't visible except for the Dock icon.

Comment: For Yosemite 10.10.3 I had to replace 'click checkbox "On" of window "Bluetooth"' with 'click button "Turn Bluetooth Off" of window "Bluetooth"'

Comment: I just get an error which suggests that application System Events isn't running?

Answer (score 3):

- Press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>, write "bluetooth".
- Press the following combination: <kbd>Fn</kbd><kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>. A light blue frame appears arround the activate box.
- Press spacebar, finished!

Comment: The sequence Fn⌃F7 activates full keyboard access; once you've turned it on you'll be able to simply tab between the control elements in the window.

Answer (score 3):

Use Alfred and the Bluetooth workflow

**Alfred**
http://www.alfredapp.com

**Bluetooth Toggle**

http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/1047-bluetooth-toggle/?hl=bluetooth

[image]

Comment: Forum link to the workflow is broken this answer is no longer viable

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the CTRL+F8 method (posted by PIXIT, down below) is exactly what I need. Here's why:
When I change the battery on my Magic Mouse, the computer often fails to reconnect the mouse. The other answers here talk about turning *Bluetooth* on or off. My Bluetooth is on, but I need to specifically activate the Mouse connection. Going through the status bar with the arrows lets me go down through the menu to My Mouse, and sideways to Connect.

(OS 10.10.3)

Answer (score 2):

I use <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>B</kbd> (Command + Ctrl + B) for this.

First install brewutil,

1. `brew update`
2. `brew install blueutil`

Second setup shoutcut,

1. Start **Automator**.
2. Open **File** -> **New**
3. Select **Service** document type. (on MacOS Sonoma it's "Quick Action" instead)
4. Now select, Service receives **no input** in **any application**
5. Now **Add action** - **Run Shell Script**
6. And now enter the following script and click save

   ```
    export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
    bluetoothStatus=$(blueutil -p)
    [[ $bluetoothStatus -eq 0 ]] && blueutil -p 1 || blueutil -p 0
   ```
7. Now go to **System Preferences** -> **KeyBoard** -> **Shortcuts** -> **Services**.
8. Go to **General** section.
9. The service created via automator will be listed there and a shortcut can be set.

The export line should be there even it is included in the `./bash-*` files.

Comment: Best answer here really, works on Catalina.

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, perfect!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Simply turn on your Mac. press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> then type "bluetooth" then press <kbd>⇥</kbd> until you reach the "bluetooth" icon.

Then <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> and <kbd>↩</kbd> to enable Bluetooth! That's the easiest way to make it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a apply keyboard (wired) - just press <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.
If you are using a Windows keyboard (wired) - just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sierra OS then you can voice activate it through Siri "Turn on bluetooth", or off for that matter. You had the option to set the keyboard shortcut when you installed Sierra. Otherwise control and space is the default/or via Spotlight.

Answer (score 1):

An updated version of the blueutil can be done using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

In a terminal:

1. Assure you have homebrew installed:

   ```
   $ brew -v
   ```

   if command not found: then install it:

   ```
   $ /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
   ```
2. update the packages

   ```
   $ brew doctor
   ```
3. install the package blueutil

   ```
   $ brew install blueutil
   ```
4. check the bluetooth status (0 means off, 1 means turned on):

   ```
   $ blueutil -p
   ```
5. set the state:

   ```
   $ blueutil -p on        # turns on the Bluetooth
   $ blueutil -p off       # turns off the Bluetooth
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to reinstall OSX from boot media, and your Bluetooth wasn't enabled at the start (still an issue with Mountain Lion Recovery media), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> gets you to the menus at the top (as described many other places), which contain other useful utilities, like Terminal.

I'm lucky that my mouse was immediately recognized (I'm sure there's ways to delve further once this has been stirred), allowing me to click things which were otherwise completely stymied (like "install"), through one short terminal command: blued . The Bluetooth daemon kicked up and gave MAC addresses for probably two devices I have currently battery powered, and around. Hope that helps others, rather than forcing us all to get/keep USB wired mice around, dust free, and in workable condition.

Other extraneous USB pointing devices failed where this method succeeded for me. The computer I am working with has a fully powered and interactive Wacom Bamboo tablet-- this doesn't get anyone anywhere since I'm sure drivers aren't included/loaded at the point I found myself.